# To assign the value of a JavaScript variable into Java variable

Tags: javascript

I have encountered a situation where I have to assign the value of a JavaScript variable into Java variable.
Please suggest me a way to do it.

P.S: Assigning value of Java variable into JavaScript is something like this:

< Script>< %

String str = "abcd";

%>
var x = <%= a %>;
/Script>

I have to do opposite of it.

Answer (score 1):

If Java is being used as the server-side language, by the time the page has been sent, Java has long finished (it doesn't run after the page has loaded). You may make a request to a page, sending the variable with the request, and that page may have Java handle the variable, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not even clear what you are doing, but I assume that the snippet you show is part of a template for a web page. You will not be able to get the variable directly - JavaScript will be running on another computer some continents apart!

But you can make the client communicate with the server, using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).